# Subdividing a simple plane does not work

Tags: modeling

I have a plane and cut it in half with a loop cut. When I try it to subdivide this is not happening. After clicking for I while I removed doubles and to my surprise some 10000 doubles were removed ?? Anyway, while in edit mode I try to subdivide this plane and it won't work. Truly ashamed I ask for a solution ...

[image: You should see my problem here. If not, I don't know what to do.]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have subdivided the edges and not the faces. If you go to vertex selection and zoom in into one of the edges, you will see many many unnecessary vertices. To fix this, just select your corner vertices (change to vertex selection, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> the corner vertices, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to inverse selection, press <kbd>X</kbd> and delect all the unnecessary vertices.

Press a until corner vertices are selected and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to face selection, then you can subdivide the faces.

If it crashes, by the amount of vertices built, you may to this, select just the corner vertices, press <kbd>P</kbd> and seperate by selection.

Exit the edit mode, delete the old object (that has huge amount of vtx), go to your new object  that has just the desired vtx, select all by pressing a, press <kbd>F</kbd>, change to face selection, subdivide.